# Heroku timeout with custom Buildpack

Tags: heroku

I have a custom Heroku Buildpack that compiles CMake and OpenCV. The problem is, OpenCV takes **FOREVER** to compile. I've tried precompiling OpenCV and pulling it in during my build; however, I have not yet been successful in doing so.

I recently came across the `COMPILE_TIMEOUT=n` env variable that can be set to override the 15 minute timeout, but it's not working. Does anyone know if this env is still supported? Or if there is another approach besides precompiling?

I would ideally like to have the flexibility of compiling on the fly if I update to the latest version of OpenCV (compilations are cached on Heroku so I'm not waiting around for a full build on every deploy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-compiling binaries is the way to go; however, it requires time and effort that I'd rather avoid. I reached out to Heroku and they were willing to increase our build time to 30 minutes. Unfortunately, 30 minutes was still not enough to compile OpenCV. The Heroku team was kind enough to [Anvil](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-anvil) which happens to be the same build service that runs on Heroku. Looks promising!

https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-anvil

Answer (score 1):

I think your best shot would be to build your binaries beforehand. However, Heroku still doesn't have great support for this.

See these links for some suggestions:

- https://discussion.heroku.com/t/compiling-a-custom-binary-for-buildpack/224
- https://discussion.heroku.com/t/opencv-and-statically-compiled-python/105